# SQL - COUNT Statement for counting quantity

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in which users can write reviews on certain products.
Each products has a category.
I am trying to do a SELECT Statement which can sort the number of reviews depending on category. I have a total of 6 Reviews of a category, yet when I am doing the select statement the result ends up as 24.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PRHYear AS 'Year',
             CategoryName AS 'Category',
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Review R
                FULL JOIN Product P ON R.ProductID = P.ProductID
                FULL JOIN Category C ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
                FULL JOIN ProductRankingHistory PRH ON C.CategoryID = PRH.PRHCategory
                WHERE C.CategoryName = 'T-Models') AS 'Reviews'
  FROM ProductRankingHistory PRH
  INNER JOIN
  Category C 
  ON PRH.PRHCategory = C.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Instead of subquery?

```
SELECT PRH.PRHYear AS 'Year',
       C.CategoryName AS 'Category',
       COUNT(*) AS 'Reviews'
FROM ProductRankingHistory PRH, Category C, Product P, Review R
WHERE R.ProductID = P.ProductID AND
      P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID AND
      C.CategoryID = PRH.PRHCateogry
GROUP BY PRH.PRHYear, C.CategoryName
```

Comment: This works with my other data, it equals to 3 which is true, but for some reason the first result is still at 24. But thank you for this.